# android icon flow menu

Tags: android, menu, icons, gallery

I would like to know how I can do a menu where the icons or photos that flows and adjust to the width of the screen and take the lines that it need to appear.

What components have I to use?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feVTk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8uuU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to use GridView 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html